# The way prevent unintended dynamic array pointer changed

Tags: arrays, delphi, dynamic, delphi-11-alexandria

Using dynamic array and I noticed unintended perform.
My code is below. It's executable as console application.

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types;

type
    TPointArray = array of TPoint;

var
    FPointArray, FDummy1 : TPointArray;

procedure AddPoint(const srcPoint: TPoint; var srcPointArray: TPointArray);
var
    i, n : Integer;
begin
    Writeln( '1: @srcPoint:' + IntToHex( Cardinal( @srcPoint ), 8 ) + ', ' +  '@FPointArray[0]:' + IntToHex( Cardinal( @FPointArray[0] ), 8 ) );
    n := Length(srcPointArray);
    SetLength(FDummy1, 1);

    SetLength(srcPointArray, n + 10000);
    Writeln( '2: @srcPoint:' + IntToHex( Cardinal( @srcPoint ), 8 ) + ', ' +  '@FPointArray[0]:' + IntToHex( Cardinal( @FPointArray[0] ), 8 ) );

    Readln;
end;

begin
    SetLength(FPointArray, 1);

    FPointArray[0].X := 100;
    FPointArray[0].Y := 200;

    AddPoint(FPointArray[0], FPointArray);
end.
```

My project has more amounts of codes, and sometimes access violation caused from other codes.
Above code is simple code, so It may not be caused access violation. But I could see the unexpected process.

For example:
At the beginning line of AddPoint procedure,
@srcPoint is $25E92F8.
@FPointArray[0] is $25E92F8.
There are same pointer.

After passed below line.

```
SetLength(srcPointArray, n + 10000);
```

@FPointArray[0] is changed to $25C6F28. (because of reallocation memory)
But @srcPoint is still $25E92F8.

So argument, srcPoint points to invalid memory location.
My project has many codes around here, so this address change leads to access violation in result.

Is there any way to avoid this, or can I only do is pay attention not to write such a code?(for example, give up to use "const" option).

Thanks.

Comment: I've been using dynamic arrays in Delphi since they were introduced, and have never encountered the issue you describe. Dynamic arrays are a managed type, and you should never be doing anything that depends on the memory address. Can you provide a [mre] in the form of a console application that demonstrates the issue, including the *invalid access*?

Comment: @Ken White  I see. Thanks for your advice and following that, I rewrote my post. I think  used memory address directly never, but my code may be equal to do that in fact.

Comment: As long as you always access the elements of a dynamic array via the array reference and an index, e.g. `MyDynArray[index]` you are safe.

Comment: @David Heffernan I see. I improved my code not using breakpoint but showing memory address in console. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg From your reply, I got knowledge, not to use one value in dynamic array as arguments. Thank you. From now on, I pay attention to write such a code.

Comment: OK, I see the issue now. Sorry, I was dumb before!

Comment: There's really not much you can do. Not using `const` is one approach. But I'm not a huge fan of that. You could take a copy inside the function, but I'm also not a huge fan of that. I think you might be best making a copy outside at the call site. It would be pretty rare I think to see this pattern.

Comment: @P.Miz there is nothing wrong with taking the address of array elements, it does make sense to do in some cases, but just make sure that you pay attention to the memory that backs the array. If the array is reallocated, the addresses of elements will change accordingly.

Comment: Hmm... It seems only be able to do is paying attention to coding. But it can be an overlooked if coding in ordinal mind. That's potential problem for me. It seems there is no effective way to prevent that, just I keep in mind from now on.